# Audio looping in phaser.js

Tags: html, audio, phaser-framework

I was wondering how to loop audio in Phaser.js.

Currently I am developing a game and I was trying to implement audio that would start again when it ends. Is there anything like sound.loop.play(); or anything.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loop` property indicates whether or not the sound or current sound marker will loop.

set `sound.loop` to `true`.

The docs can be found [here](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Sound.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need define the sound:

```
this.game.load.audio('sonido', 'url/to/sound.wav');
this.sfx.sonido = this.game.add.audio('sonido');
this.sfx.sonido.loopFull();
```

If you need set the volume, put in the function:

```
this.sfx.sonido.loopFull(0.8);
```

Comment: Is necessary set the volume in `.loopFull(#)`, this can be a integer or decimal, to work

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion about an audio bug in recent version of Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457099

So i've made a monkeypatch, it's not very pretty but it works somehow

```
this.levelMusic.play('', 0, 1, true);
this.levelMusic.onLoop.add(this.playLevelMusic, this);
```

And then with the function playLevelMusic I set it to play once again:

```
playLevelMusic: function() {
    this.levelMusic.play('', 0, 1, true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah! that works too! I found that chrome had a weird bug with looping. Coming back to this helped alot, thank you!